# How to show that a process has independent increments and is, as a result, Poisson?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

**Question**

$N$ Daleks are invading Earth, where $N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$. Assume each Dalek dies independently. Let $X_i$ be the lifetime of the $i^{th}$ Dalek in the battlefield, which is a positive random variable with PDF $f$ and CDF $F$ and $N(t)$ be the number of Daleks who have died by time $t$.

$(a)\quad$ Find the mean of $N(t)$ for each $t > 0$.

$(b)\quad$ Identify the distribution of $N(t)$ for each $t > 0$.

$(c)\quad$ Show that, for any $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq t_3 < t_4$, $N(t_2) - N(t_1)$ and $N(t_4) - N(t_3)$ are independent. What type of process is $N(t)$?

---

I have thought long and hard about this problem, but as my professor has just covered Poisson processes, I probably do not have enough exposure to know what the problem requires, so I would like to know how to approach each part. In particular, how do I show that $N(t_2) - N(t_1)$ and $N(t_4) - N(t_3)$ are independent? Any intuitive solutions for the three parts will be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit**

I have made some progress following some help from an answer. In particular, I know that $N(t)$ is a thinned Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda F(t)$. However, I am still unsure of my working for part $(c)$, which I replicate below:

Consider the case when $t_3 = t_2$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\implies & \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_3) = x, N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)]\\[1 mm]
& = \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_2) = x, N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)]\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z, N(t_2) = z + y, N(t_4) = z + y + x]\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z]P_{z, z + y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{z + y, z + y + x}(t_4 - t_2)\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z]P_{0y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{0x}(t_4 - t_2)\\[1 mm]
& = P_{0y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{0x}(t_4 - t_2)\\[1 mm]
& = \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_2) = x]\mathbb{P}[N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)]\\[1 mm]
& = \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_3) = x]\mathbb{P}[N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)]
\end{aligned}$$

Now, consider the case when $t_3 > t_2$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\implies & \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_3) = w, N(t_3) - N(t_2) = x, N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)]\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z, N(t_2) = z + y, N(t_3) = z + y + x, N(t_4) = z + y + x + w]\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z]P_{z, z + y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{z + y, z + y + x}(t_3 - t_2)P_{z + y + x, z + y + x + w}(t_4 - t_3)\\[1 mm]
& = \sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \mathbb{P}[N(t_1) = z]P_{0y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{0x}(t_3 - t_2)P_{0w}(t_4 - t_3)\\[1 mm]
& = P_{0y}(t_2 - t_1)P_{0x}(t_3 - t_2)P_{0w}(t_4 - t_3)\\[1 mm]
& = \mathbb{P}[N(t_4) - N(t_3) = w]\mathbb{P}[N(t_3) - N(t_2) = x)]\mathbb{P}[N(t_2) - N(t_1) = y)
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, in both cases, we have independence and can conclude that $N(t_2) - N(t_1)$ and $N(t_4) - N(t_3)$ are independent $\forall\ 0 \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq t_3 < t_4$. In particular, $N(t)$ is a homogenous Poisson process.

Is my reasoning sound and in particular, would I be able to actually combine both cases?

Comment: Is the lifetime PDF $f$ specified somewhere else, or is it intended to be arbitrary?

Comment: @angryavian This is the entire problem, so I suppose it is intended to be arbitrary? There are parts (d) and (e) too, but they relate to a compound Poisson process defined in part (d) itself, so I actually intended to write about it in another post once I have understood parts (a) to (c) here.

Comment: Then shouldn't your answers depend on $f$?

Comment: I'm not sure (c) is even true. It obviously is not if you replace the assumption that a Poisson number of Daleks initially exist with a deterministic number (because then if $N(t_2)-N(t_1)=N(0)$ (i.e. all the Daleks died between $t_1$ and $t_2$) then $N(t_4)-N(t_3)$ must be $0$ (they're all dead before $t_3$ so no more can die before $t_4$).

Comment: I've definitely seen incorrect/incomplete exercises written down before. But I think the Poisson nature of the initial population changes things.

Comment: It's not actually a standard Poisson process unless the lifetimes are exponentially distributed.

Comment: @Ian Yes... And the question does not provide that information (the pdf of the lifetime is deliberately left vague). According to my professor, he says that we should be able to prove this from "first principles" using the information provided in the question, but I've got no clue how to proceed...

Comment: Well, you can condition on $N(t_1)$ and sum over that, which gets you the actual value of $N(t_2)$ in each summand. Having that, you can further condition on $N(t_3)$ and sum over *that*, and at that point you have what you need. But this seems awfully laborious considering how simple the previous two parts are.

Comment: @Ian hmm… I think I am getting what you are saying. In other words, I should try to prove $N(t_2) - N(t_1)$ is independent of $N(t_3) - N(t_2)$ first and then do the same for $N(t_4) - N(t_3)$ and $N(t_3) - N(t_2)$?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about proving this for overlapping increments. You want to say that the distribution of $N(t_4)-N(t_3)$ is the same even when conditioned on a value of $N(t_2)-N(t_1)$. The distribution of $N(t_4)-N(t_3)$ depends explicitly on $N(t_3)$. So you condition on $N(t_3)$. But $N(t_3)$ depends on $N(t_2)$. So you condition further on $N(t_2)$. You already conditioned on $N(t_2)-N(t_1)$, so to know $N(t_2)$ you finally *also* condition on $N(t_1)$.

Comment: @Ian I have tried a somewhat different approach now. Would you be so kind as to take a look at my edit and see if that makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Conditioned on $N=n$, the distribution of $N(t)$ is $\text{Binomial}(n, F(t))$.

---

(a) So, $E[N(t) \mid N=n] = nF(t)$. Thus,
$$E[N(t)] = E[E[N(t) \mid N]] = E[N\cdot F(t)] = \lambda \cdot F(t).$$

---

(b) For the unconditional distribution of $N(t)$, again go through conditioning on $N=n$.
\begin{align}P(N(t)=k)
&= \sum_{n = k}^\infty P(N(t)=k \mid N=n) P(N=n)
\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} F(t)^k (1-F(t))^{n-k} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-\lambda F(t)}\frac{(\lambda F(t))^k}{k!} 
\cdot e^{-\lambda (1-F(t))}\frac{(\lambda (1-F(t)))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
\\
&= e^{-\lambda F(t)} \frac{(\lambda F(t))^k}{k!}.
\end{align}

---

(c)

$$P(N(t_2)-N(t_1) = k, N(t_4)-N(t_3)=k') = P(N(t_2)-N(t_1) = k) \cdot P(N(t_4)-N(t_3)=k')$$
for any $k,k'$. I suspect if you start from the left-hand side and do a similar conditioning on $N=n$ you can arrive at the final result with a lot of tedious accounting. Not sure if there is a slicker way. I may revisit this later.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I will be glad to see any further in-depth answers for part (c) later on, but firstly, may I know how you deduced that the probability for the binomial is $F(t)$?

Comment: @EthanMark The probability that the $i$th Dalek is killed by time $t$ is $P(X_i \le t) = F(t)$.

Comment: I have now understood fully parts (a) and (b) and I think I have also made some progress regarding (c), which I have shown in an edit to my post. Are you able to help me from there or at least tell me if I am on the right track?